# Django rest framework - Parse key value pair in post()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When user enters in POST API data, they would enter A and B key value pairs. I want to modify the post() to fit my needs. I want to parse the below when user clicks submit or posts API data.

**Anyway to parse those fields before it's returned on api view(or when user clicks submit)?**

This is what user is attempting to post using POST API.

```
[
    {
        "A": "1234",
        "B": "12345",
    },
]
```

**What I did:**

views.py

```
class MyModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModeSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     ##parse A values from key value pair so that value == 1234
     ##parse B values from key value pair so that value == 12345
     return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
class Models(models.Model):
    A = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    B = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to send a single object, not a list of objects. Because `ListCreateAPIView`'s `create` function will be creating only one object in your model.

So, if the user sends a POST request with following data:

```
{
    "A": "1234",
    "B": "12345",
}
```

You can access it from your `request.data` dictionary.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     A = request.data.get('A', None)
     B = request.data.get('B', None)
     return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If A or B is None, that would mean the data is not properly sent with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the data as key pairs. Try this:

```
class MyModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModeSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pairs = request.data()
        for pair in pairs:
            model = Models.objects.create(**pair)
        return Response({"results": "saved"})
```